# Make a C# program with .net Framework 4.5.2 work in Windows XP

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

I made a C# program for my work with .net Framework 4.5.2 because the requirements were that it just has to run at the newest Windows version. But in the end of my project it became clear that program hast to run on older OS like Win XP. Because we have some older terminal pcs and CNC-machines with Win XP at work.

So I figured out, that the newest or the last version of .net that runs on XP is 4.0. I made a copy of my program and tried to downgrade it in Visual Studio to .net 4.0.

Unfortunately when I run my program it showes the GUI for a few seconds and then it chrashes with a  `BadImageFormatException` in System.Windows.Forms.dll even it is a WPF project.

Do I have options to solve this problem or isn´t there any possibility to solve this without making to many changes in the code? I thought about making it runable on browser. But I have no idea how big this construction area will get. I think I did my best to make a clear cut between the GUI and the logic in the program but I´m afraid to do this.

Comment: Do they realize that MSFT doesn't even support XP anymore?...That's a bogus requirement

Comment: Did you read about BadImageFormatException? It seems you have a 32 bit Windows XP and you have a DLL which is 64 bit. (Or something similar)

Comment: Hm I wasn´t not amused about that, too. So as I see that it would be like the Pandora´s Box and I don´t want to be the one that opens it. Yes that point with security is very true, but most of the CNC-machines are older ones and the control sysstem is not capable of a newer windows version. I don´t know it in detail but I asked for it. I see this will give me some headaches for next time.

Comment: @rory.ap: Both of your statements are inaccurate. Running Windows XP is only a security risk, if you are running it out in the open. This is often not the case. And Microsoft **do** still produce patches for Windows XP. They are really for the embedded OS, but can be installed on the desktop version as well. Not that it is supported, but MS still actively support (some) Windows XP OS' (see [Lifecycle support policy FAQ - Windows Products](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/18581/lifecycle-support-policy-faq-windows-products)).

Answer (score 4):

`BadImageFormatException` usually means you are running a 64bit assembly in a 32bit OS

If this is your case, switching Target to x86 and recompiling should produce a working program.